# How to remove everything before a set of certain characters (e.g., "? - ")?

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr

I would like to remove everything before "? - " including the characters themselves (question mark, space, hyphen, space). I know it is possible to remove everything before a particular character. I don't want to remove everything before just the hyphen - , as I have other statements that have hyphenated words. I tried this, but it didn't work for hyphenated words.

Example:

```
gsub(".*-", "", "To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - Statistics make me cry.")
gsub(".*-", "", "To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - T-tests are easy to interpret.")

Output:
" Statistics make me cry."
"tests are easy to interpret."
```

I would like the second statement to appear as `T-tests are easy to interpret`

Comment: change the code `.*\\?\\s*-\\s*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `sub` would be enough instead of global `g`.  Change the pattern to match the `?` (metacharacter - so it is escaped `\\`), followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by the `-` and then zero or more spaces, replace with blank (`''`)

```
sub(".*\\?\\s*-\\s*", "", v1)
#[1] "Statistics make me cry."        "T-tests are easy to interpret."
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - Statistics make me cry.", 
"To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - T-tests are easy to interpret."
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try package `stringr` and use `str_split`. But it puts the results in a list so you have to pull the second element from the first list. Or start you input as a vector.

```
library(stringr)

str1 <- "To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - Statistics make me cry."
str2 <- "To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - T-tests are easy to interpret."

str_split(str1, pattern = "`? - ")[[1]][2]
```

[1] "Statistics make me cry."

```
str_split(str2, pattern = "`? - ")[[1]][2]
```

[1] "T-tests are easy to interpret."

Comment: You can do the same thing using `strsplit()` from the base package without loading an additional library. `pattern` should be changed to `split`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `stringr` in the `tidyverse`:

```
library(stringr)
str <- c("To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - Statistics make me cry.",
         "To what extent do you disagree or agree with the following statements? - T-tests are easy to interpret.")
str_split(str, ' - ', simplify = T)[,2]
```